# How to detect left and right swipes in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am using GestureDetector to check when a user swipes horizontally across the screen.

The swipe should only be registered when the user removes their finger from the screen to end the swipe, hence the use of onHorizontalDragEnd.

When the swipe ends a int is incremented resulting in a new image being displayed.

The issue I am having is that I want to be able to let the user swipe left to go back an image.

How can I detect which direction a user has swiped when implementing onHorizontalDragEnd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect swipes using the ***onPanUpdate*** method from GestureDetector class.

```
GestureDetector(onPanUpdate: (details) {
  if (details.delta.dx > 0)
    print("Dragging in +X direction");
  else
    print("Dragging in -X direction");

  if (details.delta.dy > 0)
    print("Dragging in +Y direction");
  else
    print("Dragging in -Y direction");
});
```

Note: Do not use this method with the ones that you are already using (onVerticalDragDown) or onVerticalDragUpdate().

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding onPanUpdate, this does not only trigger when when the user lets go, it does the entire time the user is dragging around, which is not what I am trying to do.

Comment: I have the same issue here, onPanUpdate method is called every time user drag their finger on the screen, which cause the function to be called multiple times unnecessarily

Answer (score 6):

Use `GestureDetector`. Example

```
GestureDetector(
      onHorizontalDragEnd: (dragDetail) {
        if (dragDetail.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx < 1) {
          print("right");
        } else {
          print("left");
        }
      },
      child: Container(...),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Having `GestureDetector`, you can use `onHorizontalDragStart`/`onHorizontalDragUpdate` callbacks together with `onHorizontalDragEnd` to get more data and determine swipe distance and direction.

However, depending on your task, it might be better to use more high-level widgets like [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

A slight Modification because the previous methods doesn't work. Use Negative for left and vice versa

```
onHorizontalDragEnd: (dragDetail) {
                if (dragDetail.primaryVelocity! < -5) {
                  print("left");
                } else if (dragDetail.primaryVelocity! > 5) {
                  print("right");
                }
              },
```